# Inserting a formula into an array based on variables and offset function

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get my code to insert a formula into an array based on how many data points there are in my data set. The code below almost works but after the first iteration of X is complete it does not insert the formula into the all the rows in the columns.

```
Worksheets(" Branded").Range("C3").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(" & r.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",RC2, " & r2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",R2C)"

For Y = 1 To Column_Limit1 - 1
    Range("C3").Offset(0, Y).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(" & r.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",RC2, " & r2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",R2C)"
    For X = 1 To Row_Limit1 - 1
        Range("C3").Offset(X, 0).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(" & r.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",RC2, " & r2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",R2C)"
    Next X
Next Y
```

Comment: using the R1C1 style normally removes the need of loops. assuming you want in `A2` the formula `=A1+1` and in `A3` `=A1+1` then you use the R1C1 formula `=R[-1]C+1` but that formula does not change and thus you can directly enter `[A2:A10].FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"`. looking at your formula which does not change, you can directly use the whole range to input it. (that also is a lot faster

Comment: You are overwriting only the first row and first column every time through the loop.  Presumably `Range("C3").Offset(X, 0).Formula =` should be more like `Range("C3").Offset(X, Y).Formula =`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to this:

```
With Worksheets(" Branded")
    .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(Row_Limit1 + 2, Column_Limit1 + 2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(" & r.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",RC2, " & r2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",R2C)"
    .Range(.Cells(Row_Limit1 + 3, 3), .Cells(Row_Limit1 + 3, Column_Limit1 + 2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R3C:R[-1]C)"
End With
```

When using R1C1 there is no need of a loop.

Comment: I just tried that but the code gives me a syntax error. Any thoughts what might be causing it?

Comment: I was missing a close `)` and the `End With`  See edit @TonyP

Comment: That fixed the syntax error. It does not fill out the full array though. The array should be 5 columns and 14 rows. This fills out 2 columns and 11 rows.

Comment: Ahhhh! I was assuming you were passing the column number to the loop, you are passing the count. See edit @TonyP

Comment: Excellent! That worked perfectly. As a side question do you have any advice on learning syntax for someone who is just beginning to learn VBA?

Comment: @TonyP troll this site and watch questions that interest you.  That and trial and error.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the help with this one!

Comment: @TonyP I hope it did not come across as flippant, I was being serious, it is how I learned.  I took one class for my MBA last year, I knew more than the teacher, because of this site and others like it.

Comment: I knew you were being serious. I appreciate the advice and  definitely plan on trolling.

Comment: How would you edit this code to also include a total at the bottom of each column?

Comment: @TonyP I usually tell the person to ask another question but see edit.